# php array format from xml

Tags: php, xml, arrays

```
$objDOM = new SimpleXMLElement(XML_FILE_NAME, null, true); // load SimpleXML
$current = $objDOM->xpath('picture');
function sort_current($t1, $t2) {
 return strcmp($t2['id'], $t1['id']); // to sort high > low
 }
usort($current, 'sort_current');
```

How come I am getting an output like this:

> Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
>   ( [0] => 9 ) [1] => SimpleXMLElement
>   Object ( [0] => 8 ) [2] =>
>   SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 6 )
>   [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0]
>   => 5 ) [4] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 4 ) [5] => SimpleXMLElement
>   Object ( [0] => 3 ) [6] =>
>   SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 2 )
>   [7] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0]
>   => 15 ) [8] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 1 ) [9] => SimpleXMLElement
>   Object ( [0] => 0 ) )

I wanted to get an output such as this:

> Array ( [0] => 8 [1] => 6 [2] => 5 [3]
>   => 4 [4] => 3 [5] => 9 [6] => 2 [7] => 15 [8] => 1 [9] => 0 [10] => )

what do I need to change to get a cleaned up array as above without all the SimpleXMLElement gubbins?
Cheers,
Andy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SimpleXML returns objects not arrays. You have to convert it, [like this guy did here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php#99729). There are a plenty of these on that page.